# Transposing or Pivoting in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I would like to know how to Transpose or Pivot a table with Customer Number, Month and Quantity so that I could be easily understood in Access 2016. I am used queries as I find them easier. So it would be of great help if anyone could help me with the function or procedure to attain the solution.

To clarify, I would like to change the below table with only two rows having the CustomerNo. 11 and 12 so that quantities are listed under each month.

```
CustomerNo.| Quantity | Month
==============================
11         | 22       | Jan 18
11         | 20       | Feb 18
11         | 18       | Mar 18
12         | 10       | Jan 18
12         | 8        | Feb 18
12         | 15       | Mar 18
```

Expected Output:

```
                |Jan 18 | Feb 18 | Mar 18 
   Customer No. |       |        |
 ==========================================
    11        |  22     |  20    |  18
    12        |  10     |  8     | 15
```

Thanks !

Comment: Easy to do in Excel.  Bring your data there.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know for now there are no PIVOT functions in access. But you can create pivot table based on existing one. In this video there is explained how https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgerpTHzQes

Alternatively you will need IIF statement like this:

```
Select [CustomerNo.], 
SUM(IIF([Month] ="Jan 18", [Quantity], 0 ) AS [Jan 18],
SUM(IIF([Month] ="Feb 18", [Quantity], 0 ) AS [Feb 18],
......
SUM(IIF([Month] ="Last month", [Quantity], 0 ) AS [Last month]

GROUP BY [CustomerNo.]
```

Bad thing about it is you need update every month your script.
If you will have better solutions I will be very thankful.